# GWT IncompatibleRemoteServiceException

Tags: java, gwt, serialization

Straight forward but maddening, I get this error on my RPC call:

An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
    com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: Invalid type   signature for com.milkrun.core.dto.UserBasket

Here is the class causing the issue:

```
public class UserBasket implements Serializable{

     private static final long serialVersionUID = -6761554796753637352L;

    public int userBasketID;
    public String description;
    public String userID;

    public List<BasketItem> items;

    public String createUserId;
    public Timestamp createTs;
     public String lastUpdateUserId;
    public Timestamp lastUpdateTs;
    public Timestamp effStartTs;
    public Timestamp effStopTs;

}
```

And the type BasketItem:

```
public class BasketItem implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -17764683871112216L;

public int basketItemID;

public String upc;
public String description;
public String brandName;

public BigDecimal price;

public String createUserId;
public Timestamp createTs;
public String lastUpdateUserId;
public Timestamp lastUpdateTs;
public Timestamp effStartTs;
public Timestamp effStopTs;

}
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and I'd rather not use IsSerializable as these DTOs are in a project shared by an android app too and IsSerializable is part of the GWT stack.

Comment: Tried that and clearing all browser cache etc. No dice.

Comment: Looking at this something tells me this will be one of those issues that's finiky

Comment: Please try using GWT compiler flag 

    strict -> true
    logLevel -> TRACE

If the compiler throws any warning/error update your question with that information.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I think it may be the List that is causing it. It shouldn't be though.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced this issue with the jetty in development mode. The problem in my case was that the jetty didnt do a "clean". I removed manually the .jar of my gwt module in workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/ (e.g. my-module.jar)

After that, the class on the server side and client site were the same again.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, simply Project > Clean... worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. If you are using eclipse GWT plugin, check the eclipse-plugin-configured (or bundled) version of the GWT against the jars that is present in your lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in DevMode in Eclipse Luna with GWT 2.6.0 and Java 1.8_0_5.
Cleaning the project, restarting Eclipse or Windows did NOT help me, but I "solved" the problem by **deploying the App to an external Tomcat** - which ran fine.
And when I returned to Eclipse, the app also ran fine in DevMode on Jetty. Weird. Smells like a bug in the GWT plugin.